# Create fixed size of database connection inside Executors.withFixedSizePool

Tags: java, multithreading, database-connection, executorservice

I'm building a multi-threaded system that uses a central database.

The problem I'm having is that I want to create a fixed size of database connections.

I used `Executors.newFixedSizePool` to create a maximum number of pooling threads equal to `MAX_N`.

I'm executing my threads using `execute` function available by `ExecutorService`.

I want to build my system in a way that each pool thread within my pool holds a single connection to the database as long as this pool thread is still alive. So, when I `execute` my threads within the pool, there is only `MAX_N` connections to the database. Also, since `Executors.newFixedSizePool` pays attention to the number of pooling thread, and creates new ones if some of them stopped because of an exception, I want the same to be hold for my database connection.

So what I'm looking for is to create a fixed size of pool thread using `Executors.newFixedSizePool`, in a way that each pooling thread has it's own connection to database. If a pooling thread terminates this connection is closed, and if a new pooling thread is constructed, a new connection is also constructed and linked to this pooling thread.

I googled a way to do this but failed to find anything helpful. Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Is it be an issue if you create a connection pool separately and when a worker  required a connection it should get from connection pool.I think if a dedicated connection then may it is not always using it.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. I need the connections count to be constant. For example, if a connection got closed accidentally, I want a new connection to be created.

Comment: that task will be delegate to connection pool.Make sure connection pool size should be same with pool size.If it is associated with thread then thread  creation also include connection creation time .

Comment: By creating a connection pool do you mean to create it as an `ExecutorService`? or to create a connection pool using my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a Jdbc Connection Pool.  then from anywhere in the code that you need a connection to the database, just get a connection to the database from the pool (the Connection Pool will be in charge of maintaining the desired number of connections to your database)

for example, if you use BoneCP:

```
import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP;
import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * <dependency>
 * <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
 * <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
 * <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
 * </dependency>
 */
public class BoneCPexample {

    public static final int TOTAL_CONNECTIONS_TO_DATABASE = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        BoneCPexample boneCPexample = new BoneCPexample();
        boneCPexample.doTheWork();
    }

    private void doTheWork() throws SQLException {


        String jdbcUrlString = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test_database";  // jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
        BoneCPConfig bcpConfig = new BoneCPConfig();
        bcpConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrlString);
        bcpConfig.setUsername("postgres");
        bcpConfig.setPassword("mi-password");
        bcpConfig.setPartitionCount(1);
        bcpConfig.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(TOTAL_CONNECTIONS_TO_DATABASE);
        bcpConfig.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(TOTAL_CONNECTIONS_TO_DATABASE);
        bcpConfig.setConnectionTimeoutInMs(1 * 1000);
        bcpConfig.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
        bcpConfig.setConnectionTestStatement("select now()");
        bcpConfig.setIdleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes(5);


        BoneCP boneCP = new BoneCP(bcpConfig);
        Connection connection = boneCP.getConnection();

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.execute("select * from mytable");

    }
}
```